# Prove automorphism

Tags: group-theory

Assume $G$ is a group. Let $\alpha(g) = g^{-1}$.

My claim is that $\alpha$ is an automorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

How do I go about this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Rightarrow:$

Suppose $\alpha$ is an automorphism. Then $\alpha(g h)= \alpha(g) \alpha(h)$. So, by the definition of $\alpha$, $(gh)^{-1}= g^{-1}h^{-1}$. Since $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$, $G$ is abelian because $h^{-1}g^{-1}= g^{-1}h^{-1}$ $\forall g,h\in G$.

Does this help with the proof overall? Let me know if you have trouble with the converse.